# Programmatic way to find the log file path for a bazel test run

Tags: bazel

I'd like to look at the log file from a bazel test run before it finishes. But bazel does not display the location of the log file unless it fails. Is there a way to programmatically find the log file location?

I understand that one can use the flag `--test_output=all` to transfer the log message to stdout, but this is often too verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bazel-testlogs/some/package/some_test/test.log` will be a symlink to the output from `//some/package:some_test`. For a test with sharding, it'll be a path like `bazel-testlogs/some/package/some_test/shard_1_of_4/test.log`.